# Possible to get all SiteCollections in a WebApplication from SPContext.Current?

Tags: object-model

I would like to look at all Site Collections that are in the current web application based on SPContext.Current.  Is there a way to do this?  If not, how can I achieve this?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

```
SPWebApplication webApp = SPContext.Current.Site.WebApplication;
foreach (SPSite site in webApp.Sites)
{
  . . .
  site.Dispose();
}
```